# UI Buttons not working in Unity ARFoundation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am creating a simple AR Scene in Unity, using ARFoundation. In which you re-spawn a gameobject and move it around using six buttons: (Rotate Clockwise, Anti Clockwise, Forward, Reverse, Ascend, Descend).

On the first phase of the scene, the user is seeing a pad on the screen, once they touch the screen, the pad disappears, and instead, a prefab re-spawns where the pad was, along with a set of six buttons.
This behavior works as expected. I can touch the buttons (And actually see the color of them change a bit) but they are not responding.

I wrote a simple script for the forward button, and seeing it is not doing anything to the gameobject. I tried to add Rigidbody to it, and upon adding gravity, I see that the physics of it work as expected, but the gameobject isn't responding to the script regardless of how I reference to it: gameobject or rigidbody.

Any idea what could cause the issue?

Of course prior each build I ensured I am referencing to all objects.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ForwardButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject aircraft;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        aircraft.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I tried following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UUb0vzmc0w&t=703s But I am not getting the same options, most likely because the guy is using Vuforia. None the less, the script above is attached to the button, and for the aircraft gameobject (First line of the class), I attached the prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me, although it's a bit ugly is to place the object on the field, hide it on initialization and instead of generating it again, I set its position to the pad's position using transform.SetPositionAndRotation and set it to active.

Would love to know though if there is a better solution rather than placing the gameobject before we actually call it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I just press this button for every scene where is Canvas with EventSystem compontent.
Unity 2021.1, AR Foundation 4.2.0 - pre x, where x is 4-7